# Solving an inequality containing complex/imaginary numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

University student here; I recently got a math task which asked me to adjust a certain point P so that the green area on the graph represents the complex numbers which fit the solution to the inequality $Re(z) ≤ Im((2+2i)*z¯)$

[Picture of the specified task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdnHZ.png)

As far as I know I need to use $z = x + iy$, which makes $Re(z) = x$ but as for the other side, I have no idea. Been at it for 1.5 hours and not gotten a correct answer yet, so would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please use $ around your formulas and write them in Tex.

Comment: Why not computing Im$((2+2i)\bar{z})$=Im$((2+2i)(x-iy))$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply calculate
$$\Im ((2+2i)\bar z) = \Im ((2+2i)(x-iy))=\Im(2xi-2yi)=2x-2y$$
which yields $x\le 2x-2y$ or $2y\le x$ which is a simple linear relation that you can fit with on point.

Comment: Thank you! I checked if this was correct by rewriting the right side of the inequality the same way you did and it turned out to be correct, but I am having problems placing the point correctly on the graph to give me the right answer. Does $2y≤x$ mean that I place the point on $[1, 2]$?

Comment: @PlzEnjoyGame the green area is bordered by the line $2y=x$, so place the point on $(1, 2)$ or $(-1, -2)$, whichever puts the green area on the correct side.